# Tabs in array java

Tags: java

When I run my code, I use 2 different arrays to display a table of data, once it is displayed, there is an unusual gap between the first and second columns.

This is what it looks like

[image]

I changed the character size and it looks like this

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstand what \t does.  It literally just put a tab character in.  You're getting exactly what you asked for.

Comment: but some have a greater gap and some dont

Comment: This is the nature of a tab character.  There is a thing called a "tab stop" [usually] at every 8th character in your output.  The "tab" character does nothing more than advance the cursor to the next "tab stop".  Example: "this\tthat" will actually output something more like "this    that", because it will force "that" to start at the 8th column.  You're seeing what you're seeing because sometimes your first column is wider than 8 characters, so it's advancing your cursor to position 16 instead of position 8

Comment: i.e.  "Hydrogen" is 8 characters long, so putting a tab after it moves the cursor to position 16.  "Helium" is only 7 characters long, so putting a tab after it advances the cursor to position 8.  You might argue that an android does not even have a tab key.  You're a victim of legacy code

Comment: the error is still there i changed the size of the characters aswell

Comment: The 7th element of the haf[] array has leading whitespace.  It's probably got a tab character in there (it should be "12.010", but in your picture it looks like " 12.010").  That's probably what's causing the issue.  You have a few other entries like that.

Comment: You can also explore `String.format()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: Instead of image, paste your code in the post (TEXT).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String leftAlignFormat = "%-4s  %-10s  %-4s %n";
        String hasan[] = {"","Hdddddd","Hdddde", "Ldddi"};
        String haf[] = {"","1.008","4.002","6.941"};
        for(int counter=1;counter<hasan.length;counter++){
            System.out.format(leftAlignFormat, counter, hasan[counter], haf[counter]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 1     Hdddddd     1.008 
> 2     Hdddde      4.002 
> 3     Ldddi       6.941
> ```